# Issue with dopost(e) function in Apple

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to write a google sheet and develop an App to get data from the sheet, send text message, and after message sent, update a field on the sheet (sms sent)

```
The goGet function seems to work, the doPost function chokes. 

const doPost = (e) => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    const [header] = sheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues();
    const Status1 = header.indexOf('Status1');
    var rowId = Number(e.parameter.row);
    sheet.getRange(rowId + 1, STATUS1 + 1).setValue('SMS Sent');
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('').setMimeType(
        ContentService.MimeType.TEXT
    );
};
```

I initially used the following tutorial to set this up: https://www.labnol.org/send-sms-google-sheets-200402

I made a few modifications. So I can't get the above function to work anyhow, when I try it out it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined doPost" Its the exact code from the tutorial with just the Status changed to Status1. Using the tutorial I already updated my sheet url and name.

So the second part is I have check boxes. I have the doGet function working using the check boxes and only sending text to the messages with the check box in front of it (If SMS1 is True,push Row[Phone], row[text1]). But I need the doPost function to update the stats field related to the which check box is true (If SMS1 is True, Update Status1 with "SMS Sent") and so on.

Full code is below:

```
// Enter your Twilio account information here
var TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SSID = 
var TWILIO_SMS_NUMBER = 
var TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 

//https://script.google.com/macros/s?A...

const SHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1.../edit#gid=0";
const SHEET_NAME = "Alert";

const doGet = () => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

    const Phone = header.indexOf('Phone');
    const Text1 = header.indexOf('Text1');
    const Text2 = header.indexOf('Text2');
    const Text3 = header.indexOf('Text3');
    const Text4 = header.indexOf('Text4');
    const Text5 = header.indexOf('Text5');
    const Text6 = header.indexOf('Text6');
    const Text7 = header.indexOf('Text7');
    const Text8 = header.indexOf('Text8');
    const Text9 = header.indexOf('Text9');
    const Text10 = header.indexOf('Text10');
    const Text11 = header.indexOf('Text11');
    const Text12 = header.indexOf('Text12');
    const Text13 = header.indexOf('Text13');
    const Text14 = header.indexOf('Text14');
    const Text15 = header.indexOf('Text15');
    const Text16 = header.indexOf('Text16');
    const Text17 = header.indexOf('Text17');
    const Text18 = header.indexOf('Text18');
    const Status1 = header.indexOf('Status1');
    const Status2 = header.indexOf('Status2');
    const Status3 = header.indexOf('Status3');
    const Status4 = header.indexOf('Status4');
    const Status5 = header.indexOf('Status5');
    const Status6 = header.indexOf('Status6');
    const Status7 = header.indexOf('Status7');
    const Status8 = header.indexOf('Status8');
    const Status9 = header.indexOf('Status9');
    const Status10 = header.indexOf('Status10');
    const Status11 = header.indexOf('Status11');
    const Status12 = header.indexOf('Status12');
    const Status13 = header.indexOf('Status13');
    const Status14 = header.indexOf('Status14');
    const Status15 = header.indexOf('Status15');
    const Status16 = header.indexOf('Status16');
    const Status17 = header.indexOf('Status17');
    const Status18 = header.indexOf('Status18');
    const SMS1 = header.indexOf('SMS1');
    const SMS2 = header.indexOf('SMS2');
    const SMS3 = header.indexOf('SMS3');
    const SMS4 = header.indexOf('SMS4');
    const SMS5 = header.indexOf('SMS5');
    const SMS6 = header.indexOf('SMS6');
    const SMS7 = header.indexOf('SMS7');
    const SMS8 = header.indexOf('SMS8');
    const SMS9 = header.indexOf('SMS9');
    const SMS10 = header.indexOf('SMS10');
    const SMS11 = header.indexOf('SMS11');
    const SMS12 = header.indexOf('SMS12');
    const SMS13 = header.indexOf('SMS13');
    const SMS14 = header.indexOf('SMS14');
    const SMS15 = header.indexOf('SMS15');
    const SMS16 = header.indexOf('SMS16');
    const SMS17 = header.indexOf('SMS17');
    const SMS18 = header.indexOf('SMS18');

    const output = [];

    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS1] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text1]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS2] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text2]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS3] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text3]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS4] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text4]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS5] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text5]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS6] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text6]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS7] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text7]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS8] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text8]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS9] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text9]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS10] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text10]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS11] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text11]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS12] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text12]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS13] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text13]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS14] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text14]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS15] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text15]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS16] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text16]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS17] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text17]]);    
        }
    }) ;
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        if (row[SMS18] === 'TRUE') {
            output.push([index + 1, row[Phone], row[Text18]]);    
        }
    }) ;
        
    const json = JSON.stringify(output);

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

const doPost = (e) => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    const [header] = sheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues();
    const Status1 = header.indexOf('Status1');
    var rowId = Number(e.parameter.row);
    sheet.getRange(rowId + 1, STATUS1 + 1).setValue('SMS Sent');
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('').setMimeType(
        ContentService.MimeType.TEXT
    );
};
```

Comment: About the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined doPost`, when you directly run the function of `doPost` with the script editor, such error occurs because the event object is not used. How about this? And I cannot understand about `So the second part is I have check boxes.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have multiple messages to send in a day, but all to the same people. I have True/False columns (SMS1, SMS2, etc) so if that column is true then send the related message (text1, text2 etc). That part works, but I need the doPost to post the "SMS Sent" message in the correlating status box. So when SMS1 is True, send Text1 to Phone and post "SMS SENT" in Status1. I have the sheet set up that when  Stuatus1  is full, the checks move to SMS2 and so on. If there is a better way to get this I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined doPost`, when you directly run the function of `doPost` with the script editor, such error occurs because the event object is not used. How about this?